# How to create an ASP.NET Server Control project in Visual Studio 2015.?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

In VS 2015, I do not see the project template for creating server control. Does any one have idea how to create custom server control in VS 2015.?

Answer (score 2):

In VS2015 server controls are no longer project templates, and are added to an existing project like other control types:

[image]